# Why is $\int \frac{dx}{x^2+1} = \arctan(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Why is $\int \frac{dx}{x^2+1} = \arctan(x)$? I understand the proofs of it, I guess I just don't get the intuition behind it. If I hadn't been taught (and then looked up the derivation) of this fact, I would've thought it was related to the natural log, like $\int \frac{dx}{x}$. So my question is, what mechanism causes this to not be of the same form?

Comment: See pages 2-3: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-b-implicit-differentiation-and-inverse-functions/session-15-implicit-differentiation-and-inverse-functions/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses15b.pdf

Comment: Just as a pointer, the use of $\arctan(x)$ is most useful to avoid complex numbers, though in a general case, I think using complex numbers are easier in many cases.

Comment: You are missing a constant for the indefinite integral.

Comment: @StubbornAtom The constant doesn't pertain to the question so I left it off.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It *is* related to the natural log, as follows. You can use partial fraction decomposition over $\mathbb{C}$ to rewrite the integrand as

$$\frac{1}{x^2 + 1} = \frac{1}{2i} \left( \frac{1}{x - i} - \frac{1}{x + i} \right)$$

and then integrating gives, at least formally,

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 + 1} = \frac{1}{2i} \left( \log (x - i) - \log (x + i) \right) = \frac{1}{2i} \log \frac{x-i}{x+i} + C.$$

It's true but not obvious that this is also $\arctan x$. The idea here is to use Euler's formula

$$\cos x + i \sin x = e^{ix}$$

to express $\tan x$ in terms of complex exponentials.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for.

Comment: Change $\log(x-i)=\log|x-i|+i\arg(x-i)$, and take advantage of the real part.

Answer (score 2):

To show a second method to solving this, see that we have the geometric series:

$$1+r+r^2+r^3+\dots=\frac1{1-r}$$

Let $r\to-x^2$:

$$1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\dots=\frac1{1+x^2}$$

Integrate both sides:

$$\int1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\dots dx=\int\frac1{1+x^2}dx$$

$$\int\frac1{1+x^2}dx=c+x-\frac13x^3+\frac15x^5-\frac17x^7+\dots$$

which happens to be the series expansion of $\arctan(x)$ for $|x|<1$:

$$\arctan(x)=x-\frac13x^3+\frac15x^5-\frac17x^7+\dots$$